# RNDIS gadget cannot start

Tags: windows, drivers, texas-instruments, davinci, rndis

I build video cameras with a Linux kernel on a TI Davinci dm365 board.

This board supports RNDIS drivers so my camera can be "plug and play" in windows. This is some kind of "Ethernet over USB" network adapter.

Windows load the RNDIS driver usb8023.sys to interact with my hardware.

When I have more than one camera plugged-in, Hell breaks loose and I get a lot of problems, sometimes all my USB ports stop working but most of the time, one of the two cameras stop working.

I've tried importing old drivers, copy usb8023.sys and load a separate driver for each cam with no luck. I've checked and double checked my ip settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded new version of the drivers from Texas Instruments and recompiled everything. I think that the problem was that the gadget pc had OTG (on the go) enabled, which allows it to switch between host and device mode.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely the USB serial numbers for each of the video cameras is identical. Windows in general handles this situation very poorly.

You need to adjust the USB descriptors on each device to be a unique ID.

Comment: this looks worth investigating. Do you have the slightest idea where I should look?

Comment: @Eric: Try looking at the g_ether source code - it should contains the descriptors.